# Dropdown menu "blinking" in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to create a dropdown menu based on Stu Nicholls' : http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro_drop8.html

Mine needs to go over *Select* dropdowns and be IE6/7 compliant, so that's why I'm using all this iFrame nonsense. Changing z-index will not fix it because IE set an infinite zindex value to select dropdowns.

So my problem is that if I copy and paste (litterally, no changes made) the dropdown menu from the website to my application it will work fine  in everything except IE6 where it will "blink". Meaning that everytime you hover over a different menu entry it will disapear for a small instant and then appear again. I think it's because IE6 consider that you're not hovering the menu anymore when you actually are.

I tried everything and browsed google for hours without finding a dropdown menu working. Do you know what could cause this problem (and maybe how to fix it) ?

Thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to fix my issue. I'm using Chrome Drop Down Menu : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/index.htm

The code is simple, pretty and works perfectly. I had some hard time customizing it but now it's done and my life is much better :

```
<div class="chromestyle" id="chromemenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu1">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu2">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--1st drop down menu --> 
<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">
<a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a>
<a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a>
<a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a>
</div>


<!--2nd drop down menu --> 
<div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenudiv" style="width: 150px;">
<a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a>
<a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a>
<a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes IE will have an issue with it's [haslayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) property. A quick easy fix is to set:

```
height: 1%;
```

Comment: on what element should i set that ? all of them ? Also won't that break the layout of my elements that already have an height value ?

Thanks

Comment: elements that have a height value do have layout, so, other elements (i am not sure your markup so I can't be specific) may not have a layout defining style property. Those are what you need to look for

Comment: Thanks! Alas, I tried setting that for all the elements without an height in my menu, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be "that guy" who suggests you use something else, so don't try this if you're set on using Nicholls' code.  But if you're not sold on Stu Nicholls' dropdown menus, you could check out [YUI's menus](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/).  I specifically mention those because I've had great success with their iframe-to-fix-ie6-bugs support.  (At the very least, you could use their sample code to see if IE6 behaves nicely with others' dropdown menus or if it's just something with Nicholls'.)

Comment: Well it's not working so I might as well try something else. I'll look at it right now.

Comment: There are a few other menus out there that work quite well in IE6/7/8, and all other major browsers (yes, even Opera) Steve has the code available for an entirely CSS-based menu at grc.com and there's a good JS-based one that I use, I just can't find the original link at the moment.

Comment: Stu's stuff doesn't impress me. I think the website name sums it up "CSS Play". His work seems to focus on the stuff you *can* do with css rather than what you *should*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is necessarilly what you need but the [jQuery bgiframe plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) handles the select problem pretty cleanly so you don't have to do everything manually.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's pretty odd, are you using native IE6 or some emulator?

Answer (score -1):

IE uses a different event trigger than the rest of the browsers. Try doing this for the mouse out:

```
        //browser sniff
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            document.getElementById('yourtriggerid').onmouseleave = function() {
                document.getElementById('themenuid').style.display = "none";
            };
        } else {
            document.getElementById('yourtriggerid').onmouseout = function() {
                document.getElementById('themenuid').style.display = "none";
            };
        }
```

`'yourtriggerid'` is whatever you want to trigger the event, and then `'themenuid'` is the menu/absolute positioned div you want to hide and show.

The key is `onmouseleave` to trigger the event for IE. Hope this helps someone!